# Binomial Distribution and the Two Slit Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

Are there any correlations between the probability of binomial distribution and the results of the two-slit experiment?

Comment: I suppose you're assuming that each peak of the interference pattern is a different $B(n,p)$ distribution?

Comment: Is there a particular significance of the dirac-delta tag here? Do you have something particular in mind? You could add some more to the question description; it's currently pretty nondescript.

Comment: @Chair https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/dirac-delta-distributions/synonyms

Comment: @KyleKanos Strange. What's the rationale behind that synonym? I thought dirac delta distributions were a pretty specific and somewhat rare distribution, with an infinitely probability value for one particular input and zero for all others. That's fundamentally different from a binomial distribution.

Comment: Apologies for the short question, what I've been and currently am thinking about is the relation between quantum and classical probability models.

Comment: @Chair if I knew the rationale, I'd tell you... Need a higher up to explain that one, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution is finite and discrete. The two-slit distribution is continuous and extends arbitrarily far. They both have a "bump" in the middle, that is about the limit of any correlation.